# Memory error for code to find sum of Even Fibonacci numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was writing code for finding sum of even-valued terms in  Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million.the code works fine for values upto 40k But I got an memory error for finding upto 4 million can someone help me resolve the problem

my code is:

```
def fib(x):
    l=[0,1]
    m=[]
    a=0
    c=0
    b=1
    while len(l) <=x:
             d=c+b
             c=b
             b=d
             l.append(d)
             if d%2==0: 
                    m.append(d)
                    a=a+d
    print 
    print a 
    print m
```

Comment: Well, you're trying to create enormously long lists.  Why no just get rid of `l` and `m` altogether, and instead just keep counters for how long they are?  Then you'll hardly use any memory at all.

Comment: how can use  counter after removing l and m

Comment: Replace `l` with `lc`, the length of `l`.  Initialize it to 2.  Replace `len(l)` with `lc`.  Replace `l.append(d)` with `l += 1`.  You can do the same with `m`, initializing it to 0.

Comment: See my posted answer below, which does exactly what I described.  It doesn't print `m`, but it prints its length.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify as I understand: You are looking for a function which returns the sum of all the even numbers in the fibonacci sequence, up to 4 million. Try it with two separate functions like this.

**The first function** for a given number in the fibonacci sequence:

```
    def fib(n):
        a = 0
        b = 1
        for e in range(n):
            old_a = a
            a = b
            b = old_a + b
        return a
```

**The second function** for the sum which calls the earlier function *(and uses a count, not a list, so as to save on memory.)*:

```
    def even_sum(t):
        total = 0
        for x in range(t):
            fib_x = fib(x)
            if fib_x % 2 == 0:
                total += fib_x
                print fib_x     # <-- this line is optional,
                                # include it if you want to see each
                                # even number printed.
        return total
```

Then call your function. For example:

`print even_sum(100)`

which gives us this answer:

`286573922006908542050`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def sum_fib(x):
    a = 0
    c = 0
    b = 1
    l = 2
    while l <=x:
             d = c + b
             c = b
             b = d
             l += 1
             # yoda conditions check
             if 0 == d % 2: # using binary should be faster (0 == d & 1)
                    a += d
    print 
    print a
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments replace l with a counter. If you **need** to print all the even fib numbers keep m otherwise remove it all together.

Initialize count

```
count = 2
```

And every time around the while loop increment count by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that eliminates the unnecessary lists, as I described in my comments.  Note that you are still going to have an exponentially-growing sum, which is unavoidable:

```
def fib(x):
    lc=2
    mc=0
    a=0
    c=0
    b=1
    while lc <=x:
        d=c+b
        c=b
        b=d
        lc += 1
        if d%2==0:
            mc += 1
            a += d
    print
    print a
    print mc
```